# Android- tools to work on actual hardware

Tags: android, testing

Is there any free tool to test android on hardware( not eclipse)?

example process:

1. connect device to PC via USB cable
2. come to homescreen > suppose homescreen have 7 tabs > default tab is tab 4
3. swipe right to left to move from tab 4 to tab 5. Again swipe to switch from 5 to 6 and so on.

I want to repeat step 3 for 1000 times, which tool can help me.

**IMPORTANT**- i want to check this on real device, not emulator.

Answer (score 2):

yes - you can use espresso to do this

Comment: Thanks, but i am not able to find a guide/tutorial to operate espresso on physical device. Most documents are related to eclipse or studio.